# Django: Filter many to many field

Tags: python, django

I expect to receive a var `contact_exists` that I can use to update some fields. However, the following query always gives me back `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: event`

Do you have any idea why `event_related_fields__event` doesn't work the way I expected?

```
for selected_order in Order.objects.all():
    contact_exists = Contact.objects.filter(
        event_related_fields__event=selected_order.event,
    )
```

Here my `models.py`:

```
class Contact(TimeStampedModel):
    consent = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_("Consent"))
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=_("Your email"))
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,  # TODO Length must be same as for billing model
        verbose_name=_("First name"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,  # TODO Length must be same as for billing model
        verbose_name=_("Last name"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, related_name='contacts')
    event_related_fields = models.ManyToManyField(
        Event, related_name='event_related_fields', through='EventRelatedFields'
    )
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(
        Organizer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='contacts'
    )  # PROTECT = don't allow to delete the organizer if contact exists

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Contact")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Contacts")
        ordering = ('created',)
        unique_together = ('email', 'organizer')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class EventRelatedFields(TimeStampedModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lead = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Lead', default=False
    )  # Contact who 'Signed Up'
    attendee = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Attendee', default=False
    )  # Contact assigned to ticket
    purchaser = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Purchaser', default=False
    )  # Contact made the order

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['event', 'contact']]
```

Comment: You have already specified `related_name='event_related_fields'` for `event_related_fields`. For that you only can use `event_related_fields__event_related_fields` to indicate the related field. Or you can modify with `related_name=event` and this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `__event` lookup, try using:

```
for selected_order in Order.objects.all():
    contact_exists = Contact.objects.filter(
        event_related_fields=selected_order.event,
    )
```

The lookup part should contain field names of `Event` model.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! I got confused because I have extra fields in my ManytoMany field. But that seems to be fine.

Comment: I just wonder what if I wanted to lookup by something else e.g. `event_related_fields=selected_order.contact` instead of `event_related_fields=selected_order.event`? Maybe there are some basics I don't understand about ManytoMany combined with `through=`